# cartesian parametrization of an equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: transformation, spherical-coordinates

I have an equation for spherical sinusoid:

$$r=a$$

$$tan (\phi) = k*cos(n*\theta)$$

And the cartesian parametrization goes:

$$x=a*cos(t)/sqrt{(1 + k^2*cos^2(n*t))}$$

$$y=a*sin(t)/sqrt{(1 + k^2*cos^2(n*t))}$$

$$z=a*k*cos(n*t)/sqrt{(1 + k^2*cos^2(n*t))}$$

I have tried to reproduce the transformation with no luck. By solving $\phi$, Matlab with syms variables gives me

$$cos(atan(k*cos(n*th))) = 1//sqrt{(1 + k^2*cos^2(n*t))}$$

but still the equations dont add up.... Could someone give me a heads up please!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: When formatting math in mathjax: (1) many symbols are obtained by preceding the symbol name with a backslash. (2) Symbols acting as operators act only on what immediately follows them. To get them to act on more than one character, put the argument inside braces {  }. (3) Special functions can often be entered by preceding the name of the function with a backslash. (4) This is not Comp Sci. Multiplication is not expressed with *. Usually we juxtapose the multiplicands. When some symbol is needed, we use `\cdot` or `\times`: $\cdot$ or $\times$. and it is $\arctan$ or $\tan^{-1}$, not "atan".